# How do I force GAP give me a true random number?

Tags: random, gap

I am using GAP (see https://www.gap-system.org/) in a number theory class to display a variety of number theoretic functions and number theory problems.  I've written code in GAP to implement the RSA encryption scheme but unfortunately, the random number generation I am using (x := Random([1..10^18]); ) gives every student the *same* random number!  The goal is for each student to generate two random primes of a certain length and use them in their RSA encryption.  This is, of course, defeated if we all get the same "random" number!

How do I force GAP to choose something truly random, something that cannot be duplicated by another student?

Comment: Good question! Try https://gap-packages.github.io/io/doc/chap6.html from the IO package. Windows GAP distribution includes IO binaries, so that should not be a problem to run it on Windows too. Linux and MacOS users should have it compiled.

Comment: I'm doing this on a Mac, using the GAP.app (which is easy for my students to use.) Regardless of how I tackle the random numbers, if I open up GAP and type Random([1..1000]); I get an answer of 859.  And, at least on the Mac, the "truly random" attempts don't change that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding my comment to include an example. You can use [really random sources](https://gap-packages.github.io/io/doc/chap6.html) provided by the IO package. It should be loaded by `LoadPackage("io");` although in most cases it will be loaded by default, if available. Windows GAP distribution includes IO binaries, so that should not be a problem to run it on Windows. Linux and MacOS users should have it compiled.

Then try the following:

```
gap> r:=RandomSource(IsRealRandomSource,"random");
<a real random source>
gap> Random(r,[1..10^18]);
607661511822560412
```

Now, in a new GAP session I have

```
gap> r:=RandomSource(IsRealRandomSource,"random");
<a real random source>
gap> Random(r,[1..10^18]);
500068505640897
```

so it seems to work as you need.

On the other hand, Alexander's number fits the purpose, and does not require you to modify an existing code by adding an additional argument to calls to `Random`, so I suggest to go for it.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that does work.  (And, yes, the package IO is indeed already loaded.)

Answer (score 6):

The default in GAP is that the random number generator always initializes with the same seed to make calculations reproducible.

One could use e.g. `CurrentDateTimeString` to re-seed the default random number generator with a changing initial value that is unlikely to be the same for two students, if they work unsynchronized.

```
Reset(GlobalMersenneTwister,CurrentDateTimeString());;
```

While this is probably not good enough for military grade cryptography, it should scramble sufficiently for classroom purposes.

Comment: Ah, thanks, Alex!  My command line > Reset(GlobalMersenneTwister,CurrentDateTimeString());; Random([1..1000]);  gives me different numbers everytime I open GAP -- that is what I need!!

Comment: Except that on Windows `CurrentDateTimeString` will return a string `"unknown"`: the code says `name := Filename( DirectoriesSystemPrograms(  ), "date" ); if name = fail then return "unknown"; fi;`